# CrudRepository class is not available int my spring boot project how can i resolve this problem

Tags: spring-boot, crud

```
package com.example.repo;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.dto.Student;

@Repository
public class StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, Integer> {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a Repository managed by Spring when using the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`, also called `InstantRepository` you need to create an interface, not a class. You don't need the `@Repository` annotation either.

```
package com.example.repo;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.dto.Student;

public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, Integer> {}
```

Make sure `com.example.repo` is a sub-package of your `@SpringBootApplication` class.

Answer (score 0):

`CrudRepository` is a part of `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`.

So add it as a dependency to your build. For maven build it'll be:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```